# In a git repo, what to do about uncovered bugs in earlier commits?

Tags: git, commit

I was given a code on which to do development work.  I committed the received version as "A" and did my work, saving it in commits "B", "C", and "D".

```
A-B-C-D
```

It was at about this point that my development work uncovered two bugs in the original code "A".  What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Why not fixing it on commit "E"?

Comment: I'm worried that, even though I don't intend on using commits A, B and C, someone might come along and decide to do just that.

Comment: Put commits A, B, C, D, and E on a feature branch, and squash them together when you merge them into `master`. Now the entire "feature" is available in a single chunk, and you don't even need to expose your local feature branch to anyone else.

Comment: Is this happening on master? A release branch? What's your branch/tag strategy? That said, *in general*, once history is shared (which is to say, on a branch multiple people are working on or from), it shouldn't be revised, but should instead be treated as immutable and added to.

Comment: If you want to add a warning to `B`, `C` and `D` indicating that they shouldn't be used (without changing them / their hashes / the commitishes of other code based on them), [see `git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes).

Answer (score 2):

There's no best practice for this one. The solution depends on how you or others will use the project.

One option is fixing over commit "D" (i.e. "E"), but this will prevent others from take the fix without your changes.

If you don't want this scenario, you can go back to commit "A", fix the bug on commit A<sup>*</sup>, and finally add your commits on top of it.

Comment: Rewriting history -- creating `A*`, and thus `B*`, `C*` and `D*` -- is only good practice if working on a branch that isn't shared by other developers yet. Otherwise, one can easy get into merge hell (try to merge a branch based off `C*` with one someone else created based off `D`, and you bring the original `A`, `B` and `C` back into history).